# List of names in array, how to never get duplicate value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of names that choose three random names and put them in a new array then print them out. How can i make it so i never get duplicate names using an IF statement? As of now, i sometimes get the same name twice when generating random names.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Students</title>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  
  window.onload = btn;

  function btn() {
   document.getElementById("btn").onclick = showStudents;
  }

  var text = "";
  var randomStudents = []; // Empty array
  var students = ["Henning", "Torstein", "Elias", "Ådne", "Dag", "Sander", "Zuz", "Braum", "Sverre", "Kayn", "Katarina", "Vayne"];

  function showStudents() {

   // Count to three
   for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
     // Take three random elements from students array and put into empty array
     randomStudents += students[Math.floor(Math.random() * students.length)] + "<br/>";
   }
   // Print out the array with random names
   document.getElementById("print").innerHTML = randomStudents;
  }

 </script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="btn">Show Students</button>
<p id="print"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: copy and remove?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using while loop. It's hard to guess when you'll generate a different name. Try this

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    // Take random element from students array
    studentToAdd = students[Math.floor(Math.random() * students.length)];

    // checks if student is already included. Generates another student if true
    while (randomStudents.includes(studentToAdd) === true) {
       studentToAdd = students[Math.floor(Math.random() * students.length)];
    }

    // adds generated student
    randomStudents += studentToAdd + "<br/>";
}
```

I also recommend adding this codes before the loop to generate new students rather than adding them to the previous set in case the user clicks the button many times

```
randomStudents = [];
```

Comment: This is it! Amazing :) Thanks for the help.

Comment: Welcome. Goodluck on your work. Please mark answer as accepted if it works on you. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

After you find a student, remove that student from the array. That way, it won’t be there the next time around.

```
function showStudents() {
  // Copy the array of students
  var tmpStudents = students.concat([]);

  // Count to three
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    // Get the random index
    var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * tmpStudents.length);

    // Take three random elements from students array and put into empty array
    randomStudents += tmpStudents[randomIndex] + "<br/>";

    // Remove the student from the array
    tmpStudents.splice(randomIndex, 1);
  }

  // Print out the array with random names
  document.getElementById("print").innerHTML = randomStudents;
}
```